# Creating multiple response set questions from SPSS file using R

Tags: r, datatable, spss, crosstab

I am new to R. I am currently creating crosstabs using PHP and R script. I am using MRSET function for creating multiple response questions but I am not getting the labels and data. It just displays the question number which is passed from PHP code.I have tried the following...

```
setwd('/files/are/inside/this/PATH/SPSS')

library(foreign)
library(expss)

expss_output_viewer()


mydata = read.spss("SPSS123456.sav", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,reencode=FALSE)


w <- data.frame(mydata)
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)



Ques<-as.character(args[1])   ## number of beds
Ban<-as.character(args[2])

Ques_Vec = strsplit(Ques, ',')[[1]]
Ban_Vec = strsplit(Ban, ',')[[1]]

temp1 <- w[c(Ques_Vec)]
temp2 <- w[c(Ban_Vec)]



Banner1 = w %>% 
tab_cells(mrset(as.category(temp1))) %>%
tab_cols(total(),mrset(as.category(temp2))) %>% 
tab_stat_cases(total_row_position = "none",label = "")
#tab_pivot(Banner1)

Banner2 = w %>%
  tab_cells(mrset(as.category(temp1))) %>%
  tab_cols(total(),mrset(as.category(temp2)))%>% 
  tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = "below",label = "")%>%
tab_last_sig_cpct(sig_labels = paste0("<span style='color:red'>",LETTERS, "</b>"))
tab_pivot(Banner2)
```

can anyone tell me where I am going wrong. I have tried the same with CSV files and it works great. The single select question works fine except these multiple select questions.

for example this is the result I am getting ...

```
         Total cases   Q13_1    Q13_2    Q13_3


Total         0           0        0        0
             0%           0%       0%      0%

Q12_1        0            0        0        0
             0%          0%        0%      0%

Q12_2        0           0         0        0
             0%          0%        0%       0%


Q12_3         0          0           0       0
              0%          0%         0%      0%
```

Comment: As written in the `expss` manual `as.category` converts dichotomy to category encoding. It seems, you don't need `as.category` at all. Just remove it everywhere.

Comment: @GregoryDemin I already tried that , but seems that the data and labels are still missing. To be very precise the labels are shown as just checked and unchecked and the data is also incorret. Am I missing something here?Maybe if you could help me out please.

Comment: You have dichotomy variables so you need something like `as.category(temp, counted_value = 'checked')`. You can replace 'checked' with appropriate word.

Comment: @GregoryDemin but how do I change the name of columns? for eg. I dont want it to show names like Q12_1, Q12_2 etc. Instead it should show the variable labels? I am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, it should show variable labels. Sorry, I can't help without reproducible example or, at least, sample of your data.